# AOS(Animation on scroll) is not working in React js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, aos.js

Here is my **App.js** Code

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import AOS from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";
import Home from "../Home/Home";
AOS.init();

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

export default App;

**Home.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="commitments">
        <p data-aos="fade-left">This is text fading</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I think this is the correct way, before using data-aos="fade-left" it working fine, But when I use data-aos the text got disappeared. I'm not getting what is the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You should run `AOS.init();` after your app mounts:

```
function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    AOS.init();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Since this library isn't designed for React, you will probably have to re-initialize this in future when your component re-renders. I recommend using an animation library built for React.

Comment: Which animation library is built for React? As I want to animate text and images on scroll.

Comment: There's a lot of them: https://www.react-reveal.com/, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animate-on-scroll, https://github.com/gilbox/react-spark-scroll, https://github.com/react-component/scroll-anim do a search and pick one that best suits your needs